# How to configure a project imported from GIT to be a Java project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I've imported a project from Git in Eclipse using this method:
File > Import > Git > Projects from Git > Next > Clone URL .

At this point I inserted the URI like this https://github.com/mygituser/My-Project .
Then my user and password, and the project was imported.

The problem is that Eclipse didn't recognize it as a Java project, and I really don't know why.

As consequence, I can't see errors or warnings on my project and neither use autocomplete, I'm getting  this message "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project".

Also, right click on My-Project > Build path shows the message "No actions avaliable".

If you need more information to help me, could you ask me on comments, please?
I appreciate your attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most people don't include build files in repositories, only source. What you need to do is create a new Eclipse project the create a Git repo on top of that:

- Create a new Eclipse project, and go to it with your terminal.
- `git init` to initialize a repo.
- `git remote add origin https://github.com/mygituser/My-Project` to add the remote.
- `git pull -u origin master` to pull the changes.

Also, make sure that when you commit, you don't add build files that the author kept out. You can do this via a `.gitignore` file. Simply take [this file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore) and add it to your project directory.

This method applies to most Git repositories, as build and compiled files are usually left out.

Note that this method requires that you install Git for command line (or Git Bash). You can get Git at [their website](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try that. Just please help me with a doubt. What do I need to do before these command lines you recommended? I'm using Windows 8.1, and git is not recognized as command.

Comment: Oh, you need to install git... I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: I suggest you install integrated into command prompt, but that's just my preference. Git Bash works too, but if you're used to windows command prompt use that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My project works fine now!!

Comment: @MariaH Glad I could help! Keep this in mind when pushing Git repos too: Gitignore your build files. Gitignore templates are available [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Comment: I just did this, except I left out the "-u" in the last command, since it was giving me an error message listing all the available commands, and "-u" wasn't there. It seems to have pulled the source, but it's ridden with errors, indicating that something is wrong in the configurations somewhere. Some enlightening info on this would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to import this project into Eclipse for 6 hours now.

Answer (score -1):

Since you already have the source code downloaded from the git repository, you should be able to create an Eclipse project from the existing source code.